# ASP.NET GridView ItemTemplate LinkButton Support for RowCommand AFTER JavaScript Confirmation

Tags: javascript, asp.net

Given the following GridView code:

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvReq" runat="server" DataSourceID="objdsReq" >
  <Columns>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Control">
      <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:LinkButton ID="lbdelete" runat="server" CommandArgument='<%# Container.DataItemIndex %>' ForeColor="Red" CommandName="DeleteReq">Delete</asp:LinkButton>
      </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>  
  </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
<asp:ObjectDataSource ID="objdsReq" runat="server" SelectMethod="GetDataTable" >
  <%-- parameter list --%>
</asp:ObjectDataSource>
```

In the RowDataBound event, JavaScript code is added:

```
Protected Sub gvReq_RowDataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowEventArgs) Handles gvReq.RowDataBound
  If (e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow) Then
    Dim lbdelete As LinkButton = e.Row.Cells(DELETE_CELL).Controls.Item(1)
    lbdelete.Attributes.Add("onclick", "javascript:if(confirm('Are you sure you want to delete?')){return true}else{return false}")
```

The JavaScript fires, but the RowCommand event will never fire - I'm guessing because it is only handled by the JavaScript:

```
Protected Sub gvReq_RowCommand(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As GridViewCommandEventArgs) Handles gvReq.RowCommand
  Dim dataItemIndex As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument)
  Dim reqID As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(gvReq.DataKeys(dataItemIndex).Values(0))
  If e.CommandName = "DeleteReq" Then
```

The JavaScript confirmation dialog was put there by requirement by Management.

Now, how do I get the RowCommand Event Handler to fire if someone clicks `OK` to the JavaScript confirm box?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/17622718/153923

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you use the `OnClientClick` attribute of the `LinkButton` instead of adding the attribute on `rowdatabound`?

Also it appears you haven't actually set the onrowcommand attribute on your grid view.

E.g:

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvReq" runat="server" DataSourceID="objdsReq"  OnRowCommand="gvReq_RowCommand">
  <Columns>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Control">
      <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:LinkButton ID="lbdelete" runat="server" 
            CommandArgument='<%# Container.DataItemIndex %>' 
            ForeColor="Red" 
            CommandName="DeleteReq"
            OnClientClick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete?');"
            >Delete</asp:LinkButton>
      </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>  
  </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

I beleive that javascript plays a large role in postback for a link button, so adding the `OnClick` in the row databound my be affecting the postback javascript.

Also check this article out for a slightly "fancier" way of doing this, instead of using the defaul javascript confirm: http://mattberseth.com/blog/2007/07/confirm_gridview_deletes_with.html

Comment: I followed the fancier way of doing this, but my `RowCommand` method is still not being fired. The item in my grid is deleted; but since my method never fires, the item still exists in the database.

Comment: Perhaps it is worth stating that the row in the GridView is deleted. It just does not delete on the database, because it never fires the `RowCommand` method.

Comment: It appear you hadn't wired up the row command event. See revised answer.

Comment: I had already replaced the `asp:LinkButton` with an `asp:Button`, so I was getting my functionality. Adding your extra RowCommand wiring caused the event to fire twice. So, I'm thinking this solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the CommandName of the Button to "Delete"

UPDATE:

instead of

```
lbdelete.Attributes.Add("onclick", "javascript:if(confirm('Are you sure you want to delete?')){return true}else{return false}")
```

try

```
lbdelete.OnClientClick = "javascript:if(confirm('Are you sure you want to delete?')){return true;}else{return false;}"
```

Comment: What, if anything, would this accomplish? After changing the `CommandName` in the HTML,n I would then need to change the `CommandName` field in the Code Behind for the `RowCommand` event handler.

Comment: "Data-bound controls recognize certain command names and automatically raise and handle the appropriate events for the control. The following command names are recognized..." [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.buttonfield.commandname.aspx)

Comment: That obviously does something, but now I have the JavsScript error **Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException: Deleting is not supported by ObjectDataSource 'objdsReq' unless the DeleteMethod is specified.**

Comment: In the markup of the gridview you can add several events: OnRowCommand, OnRowDeleted, OnRowDeleting. This error is saying that you need to append the delete event to the gridview.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowdeleting.aspx

Comment: Hmmm... I'm trying to *patch* a VB app that another developer wrote about 3 years back. He already has code behind to handle the **Delete** Row Command. Would this mean I need to ditch the code behind and wire stuff up in the HTML?

Comment: I updated my answer, maybe that helps you. Put the ; after return true; and return false;